# How to find the columns that need to be indexed?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I'm starting to learn SQL and relational databases. Below is the table that I have, and it has around 10 million records. My composite key is `(reltype, from_product_id, to_product_id)`.

What strategy should I follow while selecting the columns that needs to be indexed? Also, I have documented the operations that would be performed on the table. Please help in determining which columns or combination of columns that need to be indexed?

Table DDL is shown below.

Table name: `prod_rel`.

Database schema name : `public`

```
CREATE TABLE public.prod_rel (
reltype varchar NULL,
assocsequence float4 NULL,
action varchar NULL,
from_product_id varchar NOT NULL,
to_product_id varchar NOT NULL,
status varchar NULL,
starttime varchar NULL,
endtime varchar null,
primary key reltype, from_product_id, to_product_id)
);
```

Operations performed on table:

```
select distinct(reltype ) 
from public.prod_rel; 

update public.prod_rel  
   set status = ? , starttime = ? 
where from_product_id = ?;

update public.prod_rel  
   set status = ? , endtime = ? 
where from_product_id = ?;

select * 
from public.prod_rel  
where from_product_id  in (select distinct (from_product_id) 
                           from public.prod_rel 
                           where status = ? 
                           and action in ('A', 'E', 'C', 'P') 
                           and reltype = ? 
                           fetch first 1000 rows only);
```

Note: I'm not performing any JOIN operations. Also please ignore the uppercase for table or column names. I'm just getting started.

Comment: Thank you @LaurenzAlbe. I have updated the tag

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function it always applies to all columns of the select list. Adding parentheses around a column won't change that. `distinct (a)` is the same as `distinct a` - and `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: I agree with Laurenz that it's nice to see someone that cares during planning phase. But don't overdo it at the beginning. I also question the use of `reltype` as you did. Obviously I don't know what you put in there, but a separate table `reltype` with a reltype_id foreign key in the `prod_rel` table might be worthing thinking about. `select distinct reltype from prod_rel` then gets as simple as `select * from reltype`

Comment: If you really want to understand indexing, I suggest you head over to: http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Comment: Thank you for sharing the link @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideal would be two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ON prod_rel (from_product_id);

CREATE INDEX ON prod_rel (status, reltype)
   WHERE action IN ('A', 'E', 'C', 'P');
```

Your primary key (which also is implemented using an index) cannot support query 2 and 3 because `from_product_id` is not in the beginning. If you redefine the primary key as `from_product_id, to_product_id, reltype`, you don't need the first index I suggested.

Why does order matter? Imagine you are looking for a book in a library where the books are ordered by “last name, first name”. You can use this ordering to find all books by “Dickens” quickly, but not all books by any “Charles”.

But let me also comment on your queries.

The first one will perform badly if there are lots of different `reltype` values; try raising `work_mem` in that case. It is always a sequential scan of the whole table, and no index can help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you please let me know why an separate index is required for from_product_id which is also part of composite key. As per my understanding, composite keys or primary keys are always indexed. Also please suggest why did you select the combination of  "status, reltype, action" as a single index?. For the last query, my requirement is to fetch the top 1000 "Not completed" distinct from_product_id rows. Note: In my table one from_product_id has many to_product_ids. Please let me know how to achieve using self join.

Comment: @TechGuy:  You don't need an additional index on `from_product_id` if you change your primary key definition to e.g. `primary key (from_product_id, to_product_id, reltype)` (putting `from_product_id` at the front)

Comment: Does order matter ?   @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @TechGuy: not for the logical representation of the primary key, but for the index that is used in the background. Index columns can only be efficiently used from left to right. So the (unique) index on `reltype, from_product_id, to_product_id` can't be used for `where from_product_id = ?` but the unique index on `from_product_id, to_product_id, reltype` can be used by that where condition. And you don't need an additional index just to support the search for the `from_product_id`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I followed your suggestion to change the primary key order to (from_product_id, to_product_id, reltype) and got rid of from_product_id index and created only one index with  (from_product_id, reltype, status, action) since I'm performing a select operation using these four columns and the response time reduced to half compared with previous response times.

Comment: I have reworked and improved my answer. Kudos to all who added good input in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the order of primary columns as shown below as per @a_horse_with_no_name 's suggestion and created only one index for (from_product_id, reltype, status, action) columns.

```
CREATE TABLE public.prod_rel (
reltype varchar NULL,
assocsequence float4 NULL,
action varchar NULL,
from_product_id varchar NOT NULL,
to_product_id varchar NOT NULL,
status varchar NULL,
starttime varchar NULL,
endtime varchar null,
primary key reltype, from_product_id, to_product_id)
);
```

Also, I have gone thorough the portal suggested by @a_horse_with_no_name. It was amazing. I came to know lot of new things on indexing.

https://use-the-index-luke.com/